# Powershell command prompt prints ^C when pressing Ctrl+C, why?

Tags: powershell

My command shell of choice is Powershell, I always have a couple of windows open where I run my scripts.

I have noticed that at some point the shell starts misbehaving in a very annoying way:

1. Press a key - **nothing is output!** Press another one - it works fine and the rest of the keys are processed as expected until you hit Enter to execute. The command runs, the new command prompt appears and **again the first key is ignored!**
2. Pressing Ctrl+C displays ^C instead of cancelling the current prompt and showing the new one.

The strangest thing is that the shell starts fine, works for some time, then gets botched in the aforementioned way and then after some period of time returns back to working fine.

This is extremely confusing, I had a botched shell instance when I started this question, but now it is fine.

Has anybody encountered a similar thing? What could be causing it?

**EDIT**

I use the console shell exclusively, not ISE. The shortcut command is:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

The shell version is:

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.17065
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

**BTW, it is botched again!**

**EDIT**

The problem did not go away. The powershell gets botched almost every day. Like now, for example. Checked `[Console]::TreatControlCAsInput` - it is `True` !!! Rechecked it a couple of minutes later - it is `False` again !!! And now Ctrl+C is working as expected again.

What is going on?

Comment: Are you using the console shell or ISE? What is your PS Version. I have had lots of odd behavior with ISE mostly due to Intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your second question about Ctrl+C you should try Ctrl+Shift+C or Ctrl+X to cancel current prompt

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+C` prints out `^C` and `Ctrl+X` prints out `^X`.