# A simple PowerShell script that botches the PS console

Tags: windows, powershell

This question is related in spirit to [Powershell command prompt prints ^C when pressing Ctrl+C, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410011/powershell-command-prompt-prints-c-when-pressing-ctrlc-why) - both deal with the PowerShell console being screwed up.

Given:

- Windows 10 or 8 or 8.1
- PowerShell console

Consider the following script:

```
$iisexpress = "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"
$config = "c:\xyz\.vs\config\applicationhost.config"
$logFile = "$env:temp\1.log"
$id = (Start-Process $iisexpress "/site:Site1","/config:$config" -PassThru -RedirectStandardOutput $logFile -NoNewWindow).Id
$id
```

I do not think having a solution specific configuration matters here. What matters is that I am starting a site while redirecting the output and collecting the process Id.

That's it. Try working with the console a bit. If nothing happens - run the script again, even though it should not be necessary. The console is botched.

Why? How do I fix it?

Comment: Has this been happening for some time now, or might it have been introduced by this month's updates?  Any idea about the circumstances in which it happens?

Comment: If everyone were hitting it trivially, there'd be a lot of noise among those of us that use it regularly... So I'm guessing it's more your environment.  Possibly something in your profile, or a script you run?  What typically leads to.it?  Does it happen in ISE as well?

Comment: I did a further investigation and changed the question to reflect the findings.

Comment: Do you have handling of control key combinations enabled in console settings?

Comment: I will check if you tell me how to :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it's the `-NoNewWindow` flag that is causing you trouble.  iisexpress.exe runs from within the Powershell window with this switch, and seems to partially hijack your input.

I'm still curious to investigate why this happens and have no answer as of yet, but an easy fix is to replace `-NoNewWindow` with `-WindowStyle hidden`